# Linux bash: How to group a ip list into common subnets?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ip

I've a huge list of IP's which is already sorted, but I still need to group them into subnet. For instance:

```
223.247.184.95
223.247.186.243
223.247.208.16
223.247.209.139
223.84.128.24        
223.84.159.214       *
223.84.159.245       *
```

The market IP's with the "*" should all be grouped by '223.84.159.*'. There
is no database, just this text file with 10.000 entries !

I tested awk and uniq commands, but my results are all not what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, could you please use code tags and show more clearly sample input and expected output please.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Your input already **has** the IPs grouped by subnet so it's not clear what you actually want to output that's different from your input. [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and show the expected output given that input.

Comment: Also, with CIDR, we don't know if a particular (say) class C has been split into smaller subnets. Do you just want the Class A / Class B / Class C subnet divisions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, as you haven't shown the output. Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you, it will print only those lines which have `*` in them from Input_file.

```
awk '$2=="*"{print $1}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I strongly suspect the `*`s don't really exist in the input and the OP (unfortunately!) added them to highlight those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Say your IP's are in a file called `ips` spread over different fields over different lines and the field separator is the default one, namely a space.

Example: 
`cat ips`

```
223.247.184.95 223.247.186.243 223.247.208.16 223.247.209.139 223.84.128.24
223.84.159.214* 223.84.159.245*
```

then for

**Unsorted IPs file**: the following awk code

```
cat ips | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,a,".");k=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3];h[k]=h[k]" "$i}}END{for(k in h)printf(k": "h[k]"\n")}'
```

gives you a hash table of the different C domains:

```
223.247.184:  223.247.184.95
223.247.186:  223.247.186.243
223.84.159:  223.84.159.214* 223.84.159.245*
223.84.128:  223.84.128.24
223.247.208:  223.247.208.16
223.247.209:  223.247.209.139
```

**Sorted IPs file**: If the file containing your IP has been previously sorted, then there is a more efficient and faster one-liner

```
cat ips| awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,a,".");cn=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]; if(cn != c){c=cn;printf("\n"c": ")};printf($i" ")}}END{printf("\n")}'
```

giving you as well

```
223.247.184: 223.247.184.95
223.247.186: 223.247.186.243
223.247.208: 223.247.208.16
223.247.209: 223.247.209.139
223.84.128: 223.84.128.24
223.84.159: 223.84.159.214* 223.84.159.245*
```

Comment: Those are [useless uses of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: @tripleee Cheese! When will these fundamentalists of pipe stop annoying around: Those uses of cat are perfectly valid and even elegant: You just need to know when/where (not) to use them. Besides: it's totally off-topic -unless you can prove here that it isn't.

Comment: In this individual example, it is obviously fairly harmless, but it continues to be poor advice; how do you know the OP, or a future visitor, doesn't need this to be run inside a tight loop millions of times?

Comment: @tripleee That's exactly my point: The OP and anybody else needs to learn on their own. The problem stated is not about efficiency. Btw, no offence intended in my previous comment. It's just that it has become a trend to criticize this use of cat, **irrespectively of the context**.

Comment: [usesful vs useless uses of cat (UvUUC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I'm obviously well aware of that question, but your link prompted me to post an answer of my own.